# Mutex c#.how system recognize mutually exclusive codes

Tags: c#, .net, mutex

I have  method a() in project A

and method b() in project B

I need to make both method mutually exclusive

at present my code I  follows

in the project A

```
Mutex mutex = new Mutex(fale,"MT");
 mutex.WaitOne();
 //SOME LENGTHY CODE
 mutex.ReleaseMutex();
```

in the project B I have

```
Mutex mutex = new Mutex(fale,"MT");
mutex.WaitOne();
//some different lengthy code
mutex.ReleaseMutex();
```

I could see both he function works mutually exclusive as expected.

Now I have 2   questions here

**One**:I use name name “MT” in both the methods.
This is the  reason why this  2 code became mutually exclusive.

Is there any different way   that this 2  codes are mutually exclusive even if I use different name?

**Two**:suppose the code on project A goes in to an infinite loop
how can I start method in B?(how can  i avoid dead lock)

Comment: 1. No.  2. That's a fale whale.  You cannot expect reasonable behavior out of unreasonable code of course.  You can detect it, WaitOne() has an overload that takes a timeout.

Comment: Suggest you explicitly add in the prefix "Global\" or "Local\" to your Mutex name to make it clear whether your mutex has [session or machine scope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way `Mutex` work is by having two proceeses requesting ownership on the **same** object, so that the first one gets it and the second must wait until the first releases it. The name is what the system uses to determine if they're the "same" or not, so using a different name will allow access to both at the same time (since each one request ownership of its own `Mutex`, which nobody else claims).

About the second question, an infinite loop is not exactly a deadlock, I think it's more than a bug in the first process than anything else. Even in a simple program, such a thing is an error and the program would crash. A timeout might solve it, but it may create another problem if there is a shared resource held (which is a reason why you use it mutually exclusive access in the first place). I would take precautions in avoiding such bugs in the first place, or if it can legitimally happen, release the Mutex early.